# PHP loop through array of objects - invalid argument error

Tags: php

I'm getting an error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` even though my foreach loop is working, barely. Can someone help clarify please?

Input:

```
$inputs = array(
    (object)array(
        "id" => 123456789,
        "act" => "AAA",
        "date" => "2020-01-01",
    ),
    (object)array(
        "id" => 987654321,
        "act" => "BBB",
        "date" => "2020-01-02",
     )
);
```

For loop:

```
foreach ((array)$inputs as $key=>$object) {
    foreach ($object as $key=>$value) {
        var_dump($value);
        echo "BREAK";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
object(stdClass)#44827 (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(123456789)
    ["act"]=>
    string(8) "AAA"
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2020-01-01"
}
BREAKobject(stdClass)#44826 (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(987654321)
    ["act"]=>
    string(8) "BBB"
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2020-01-02"
}
BREAKobject(stdClass)#44825 (2) {
    ["code"]=>
    string(14) "INTERNAL_ERROR"
    ["description"]=>
    string(39) "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"
}
```

Edit: Add missing }

Edit: Looks like my company has a function that changes the input into the following:

```
object(Special\Type)#45152 (2) {
    ["_input":protected]=>
        object(stdClass)#45151 (2) {
        ["0"]=>
            object(stdClass)#45148 (5) {
            ["id"]=>
            int(101)
            ["act"]=>
            string(8) "AAA"
            ["date"]=>
            string(10) "2020-01-01"
        }
        ["1"]=>
            object(stdClass)#45147 (5) {
            ["id"]=>
            int(102)
            ["act"]=>
            string(8) "BBB"
            ["date"]=>
            string(10) "2020-01-02"
        }
    }
    ["_nameInJson":protected]=>
    string(0) ""
}
```

Comment: should before the loop check if the `$object` is an array.

Comment: [Not reproducible](https://onecompiler.com/php/3ykwnkqqv)

Comment: @Lessmore can't you also use foreach for objects?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing ending bracket to your first foreach loop.

There is also another problem in your code: It is that you assign new $key variable in another foreach loop. It does not really affect your code now, but if you want to use $key of first foreach loop it would not be possible because you assign it again in the second loop.

Comment: Oops, the } was just a copy/paste error when I was trying to remove company specific data. I also don't care about the $key. It seemed like it still runs (with the error) when I remove the `$key=>` at each level